# Writing C program for user to input 50 or less numbers

Tags: c, user-input

I am trying to write a C program that has to ask the user for input to take in 50 or less numbers. My problem is the "or less" numbers. How do I get the program to know when the user wants to stop entering numbers?

Comment: I think you are using scanf to input the number. The normal practice is if the user enters 0, -1 or [blank] then you regard the user has completed and wants to stop.

Comment: @KenLee As per your suggestion, user can enter any number of inputs and doesn't stop at 50

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html))

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[100],n,i;
    printf("Enter the no of inputs u want to give (It must be less than or eqaual to 50)\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the nos \n");
    if(n<=50)
    {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid Input \n");
        getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle user input of some unknown number of inputs, is simply to read all input with `fgets()` and allow the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty-line when done with input. You also must check for a manual `EOF` because it is valid for the user to press <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows) to cancel input. (you generally want to exit gracefully if the user does that)

Reading with `fgets()` you read input into a character array. All *line-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgets()` and POSIX `getline()`) read and include the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> following each input in the buffer they fill. So just check if the first character in the buffer is the `'\n'` character to see if the user is done with input and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty-line.

A short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXI   50

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold user input */
    int array[MAXI];    /* array to hold up to MAXI integer values */
    size_t n = 0;       /* counter for number of integers in array */
    
    printf ("\nEnter up to %d integers, Press [ENTER] on empty-line to end:\n\n", MAXI);
    
    while (n < MAXI) {                                  /* while array not full */
        printf (" array[%2zu]: ", n);                   /* prompt for input */
        
        if (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {        /* if manual EOF, quit */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            return 0;
        }
        if (line[0] == '\n')                            /* if Enter on empty-line, done */
            break;
        
        if (sscanf (line, "%d", &array[n]) == 1)        /* if valid integer */
            n += 1;                                     /* increment counter */
        else    /* otherwise, handle error */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    
    puts ("\narray content:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" array[%2zu] : %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

(**note:** how the loop condition  `while (n < MAXI)` ensures you never write more integers to your array than it can hold)

**Example Use/Output**

The program fully validates the integer input and handles any non-integer input as well by simply informing the user though an error message and then re-prompting for the input:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_n_integers

Enter up to 50 integers, Press [ENTER] on empty-line to end:

 array[ 0]: 10
 array[ 1]: 20
 array[ 2]: Three Hundred Twenty-Six!!!
  error: invalid integer input.
 array[ 2]: 30
 array[ 3]: 40
 array[ 4]: 50
 array[ 5]: Are we done yet?, No Press [Enter] on an empty-line!
  error: invalid integer input.
 array[ 5]: 60
 array[ 6]: 70
 array[ 7]: 80
 array[ 8]: 90
 array[ 9]:

array content:

 array[ 0] : 10
 array[ 1] : 20
 array[ 2] : 30
 array[ 3] : 40
 array[ 4] : 50
 array[ 5] : 60
 array[ 6] : 70
 array[ 7] : 80
 array[ 8] : 90
```

Look things over, give it a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to allow user to enter inputs not more than 50 times. You can simply use a variable to count the number of inputs like:

```c
int main()
{
    int input, count=0;
    printf("Enter not more than 50 inputs\n");
    while (count < 50)
    {
      printf("Remaining inputs: %d\n", 50-count);
      scanf("%d", &input); // I just use an integer input for this answer
      printf("Entered: %d\n", input); // frame your own logic to handle the inputs
      count++;
    }
    printf("Done!");
    return 0;
}
```